# What does the @unique decorator do in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, enums, decorator

I recently came across this code:

```
@unique
class NetlistKind(IntEnum):
  Unknown = 0
  LatticeNetlist = 1
  QuartusNetlist = 2
  XSTNetlist = 4
  CoreGenNetlist = 8
  All = 15
```

What does the `@unique` decorator do, and what is its purpose in the above snippet?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

##### Summary

`unique` is a class decorator for `Enum` that raises a ValueError if there are any duplicate enumeration values.

This code

```
from enum import unique, Enum

@unique
class Mistake(Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3
    FOUR = 3
```

Produces this error:

```
ValueError: duplicate values found in <enum 'Mistake'>: FOUR -> THREE
```

##### More Details

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html):

###### Context

> By default, enumerations allow multiple names as aliases for the same value. When this behavior isn’t desired, [unique] can be used to ensure each value is used only once in the enumeration

###### Description

> [unique is] a class decorator specifically for enumerations. It ensures only one name is bound to any one value [in an enum]. [unique] searches an enumeration’s `__members__` gathering any aliases it finds; if any are found ValueError is raised with the details

Comment: Do we require `unique` if we are using `auto`?

Comment: "require"... no, but it doesn't hurt.  @unique might still be a good idea if you want to help future 'you' or whoever touches the code next, to be sure the values are all unique.  Incase some future edit of the code doesn't use auto, or some other obscure reason causes a duplicate.

Comment: In this particular case, you may also want to look at using a Flag: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/enum.html#enum-class-differences